# Wrapfigure keeps space for rest of page

Tags: spacing, wrapfigure

Can anyone helped me with this? I've looked up questions with similar problems but nome of them seem to work for me. I'm writing a book and I like to use `wrapfig` for site-notes for recalls or notation etc. Throughout the book, the wrapped-figure reserves space below it for the rest of the page. `\clearpage` fixes the problem but I don't want to start a new page after each `wrapfigure`. Help :(

Here's the particular case I'm dealing with: [image]

I want the paragraph under the diagram to spread out over the whole page. An MWE of the above can be found below.

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \usepackage{framed}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}
        \begin{document}
    \subsection*{What is Differentiation?}
    Differentiation is a mathematical tool used to find the \textbf{gradient of a tangent} to any general curve $y=f(x)$ at any desired point ($P$).
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
        \draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
        \draw[thick, color=gray,->] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {\textcolor{black}{$x$}};
        \draw[thick, color=gray, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {\textcolor{black}{$f(x)$}};
        \draw [color=red, semithick](-4,1).. controls(1,1.5).. (3.5,5);
        \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$P(x,y)$}] (P) at (1.15,2.15) {};
        \draw (3,4) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
        \draw (-1,3/5+0.05)--(3,34/10+0.05);
        \draw (-0.3,0.3) node[left]{tangent};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{center}
    In general, the steepness (i.e. gradient) of a curve at any point $P$ is the same as the gradient of the tangent at that point; i.e.
    \[m_{\text{tangent at P}}=m_{f(x)\text{ at P}}\]
    In calculus, $m_{f(x)\text{ at P}}$ is denoted \[\displaystyle\frac{d}{dx}\left(f(x)\right)\text{~~or~~~~} \displaystyle\frac{dy}{dx}\] when the equation is defined in the form $y=f(x)$, and we call this general gradient the \textbf{derivative} of the curve. \paragraph{}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{r}{5.5cm}
        \vspace{-1cm}
        \begin{center}
            \begin{minipage}{5cm}
                \colorlet{shadecolor}{green!15}
                \begin{shaded}
                    \normalsize \textbf{Notation}
                    \Large $$\delta x$$
                    \normalsize The Greek letter $\delta$ (small-case delta) is a \textbf{prefix} to a variable and it represents an infinitesimally small increase in that variable. It is not a distinct value. 
                \end{shaded}
            \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    Consider now another point on our general curve, the point Q. This point is $\delta x$ away from $P$ horizontally and $\delta y$ away from $P$ vertically:\\
        \begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
        \draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
        \draw[thick, color=gray,->] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {\textcolor{black}{$x$}};
        \draw[thick, color=gray, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {\textcolor{black}{$f(x)$}};
        \draw[color=blue] (1.15,2.15)--(3.3,4.7);
        \draw [color=red, semithick](-4,1).. controls(1,1.5).. (3.5,5);
        \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$P(x,y)$}] (P) at (1.15,2.15) {};
        \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=right:{$Q(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)$}] (Q) at (3.3,4.7) {};
        \draw (3,4) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
        \draw (-1,3/5+0.05)--(3,34/10+0.05);
        \draw (-0.3,0.3) node[left]{tangent};
        \draw[dotted] (3.3,4.7)--(3.3,4.3);
        \draw[dotted] (3.3,3.7)--(3.3,0);
        \draw[dotted] (1.12,2.15)--(1.12,0);
        \draw[dotted] (3.3,4.7)--(0,4.7);
        \draw[dotted] (1.12,2.15)--(0,2.15);
        \draw[<->,dashed](-0.3,2.15)--(-0.3,4.7);
        \draw(-0.6, 3.4) node{$\delta y$};
        \draw[<->,dashed](1.15,-0.3)--(3.3,-0.3);
        \draw(2.3, -0.6) node{$\delta x$};
        \end{tikzpicture}\\
        The coordinates of $Q$ are $(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)$, shown above. We notice that if the values of $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ were to get smaller and smaller, the gradient of the chord $PQ$ (in blue) would approach that of the tangent at $P$, the gradient we wish to find ($\frac{dy}{dx}$). We also know that the $y$-values of this graph are dependent on their respective $x$-value, since $y$ is defined as a function of $x$ ($y=f(x)$). So as $\delta x$ decreases, $\delta y$ will consequentially decrease because $(y+\delta y)$ is dependent on $(x+\delta x)$. So we can say that as $\boldsymbol{\delta x\longrightarrow 0}$;  $\boldsymbol{m_{PQ}\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}}$. 
    \end{document}
```

I appreciate your feedback :)

Comment: I suspect `wrapfig` does not realize how much vertical space your `tikzpicture` is taking up, and thus continues to wrap lines of text until it has decided it has wrapped enough. The `\clearpage` probably just "forces" the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You only have to set the number of lines that will be wrapped as an optional argument to the environment:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[3]{r}{5.5cm}
 …
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Alternatively, you might try the `InsertBoxR` generic macro in the place of the `wrapfigure` environment: use

```
......
\input{insboxtex}
\begin{document}
......

\InsertBoxR{0}{%
 \begin{minipage}{5cm}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{green!15}
    \vskip\dimexpr-\FrameSep-0.6ex\relax
\begin{shaded}
\normalsize \textbf{Notation}
\Large $$\delta x$$
    \normalsize The Greek letter $\delta$ (small-case delta) is a \textbf{prefix} to a variable and it represents an infinitesimally small increase in that variable. It is not a distinct value.
\end{shaded}
\end{minipage}}[-2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `wrapfig` for this. You also don't need `framed` and `amsbsy` (you're abusing `\boldsymbol`, where `\boldmath` should be used if you *really* want to make math bold).

I also removed `\left`, `\right` and `\displaystyle` where unnecessary.

Instead of a non working `wrapfig` environment, use `tabular`, since you want to place something that won't allow flowing around the insertion.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,tabularx,framed}

\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}

\newlength{\normalparindent}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}}
\newcommand{\normalindent}{\hspace*{\normalparindent}}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{What is Differentiation?}

Differentiation is a mathematical tool used to find the \textbf{gradient of a tangent} to 
any general curve $y=f(x)$ at any desired point ($P$).
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
  \draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
  \draw[thick, color=gray,->] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {\textcolor{black}{$x$}};
  \draw[thick, color=gray, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {\textcolor{black}{$f(x)$}};
  \draw [color=red, semithick](-4,1).. controls(1,1.5).. (3.5,5);
  \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$P(x,y)$}] (P) at (1.15,2.15) {};
  \draw (3,4) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
  \draw (-1,3/5+0.05)--(3,34/10+0.05);
  \draw (-0.3,0.3) node[left]{tangent};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
In general, the steepness (i.e. gradient) of a curve at any point $P$ is the same as the 
gradient of the tangent at that point; i.e.
\[
m_{\text{tangent at $P$}}=m_{f(x)\text{ at $P$}}
\]
In calculus, $m_{f(x)\text{ at $P$}}$ is denoted
\[
\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{dy}{dx}
\]
when the equation is defined in the form $y=f(x)$, and we call this general gradient the 
\textbf{derivative} of the curve.\strut

\noindent\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  p{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-5cm-12pt}
  c
  @{}
}
\normalindent Consider now another point on our general curve, the point Q. This point 
is $\delta x$ away from $P$ horizontally and $\delta y$ away from $P$ vertically:
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4,scale=.95]
  \draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
  \draw[thick, color=gray,->] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {\textcolor{black}{$x$}};
  \draw[thick, color=gray, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {\textcolor{black}{$f(x)$}};
  \draw[color=blue] (1.15,2.15)--(3.3,4.7);
  \draw [color=red, semithick](-4,1).. controls(1,1.5).. (3.5,5);
  \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$P(x,y)$}] (P) at (1.15,2.15) {};
  \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=right:{$Q(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)$}] (Q) at (3.3,4.7) {};
  \draw (3,4) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
  \draw (-1,3/5+0.05)--(3,34/10+0.05);
  \draw (-0.3,0.3) node[left]{tangent};
  \draw[dotted] (3.3,4.7)--(3.3,4.3);
  \draw[dotted] (3.3,3.7)--(3.3,0);
  \draw[dotted] (1.12,2.15)--(1.12,0);
  \draw[dotted] (3.3,4.7)--(0,4.7);
  \draw[dotted] (1.12,2.15)--(0,2.15);
  \draw[<->,dashed](-0.3,2.15)--(-0.3,4.7);
  \draw(-0.6, 3.4) node{$\delta y$};
  \draw[<->,dashed](1.15,-0.3)--(3.3,-0.3);
  \draw(2.3, -0.6) node{$\delta x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center} &
\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}%
\smash{\colorbox{green!15}{%
\begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
\textbf{Notation}
\begin{center}
\Large $\delta x$
\end{center}
The Greek letter $\delta$ (small-case delta) is a \textbf{prefix} to a variable and it 
represents an infinitesimally small increase in that variable. It is not a distinct value.
\end{minipage}}}
\end{tabular}
The coordinates of $Q$ are $(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)$, shown above. We notice that if the 
values of $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ were to get smaller and smaller, the gradient of the 
chord $PQ$ (in blue) would approach that of the tangent at $P$, the gradient we wish to find 
($\frac{dy}{dx}$). We also know that the $y$-values of this graph are dependent on their 
respective $x$-value, since $y$ is defined as a function of $x$ ($y=f(x)$). So as $\delta x$ 
decreases, $\delta y$ will consequentially decrease because $(y+\delta y)$ is dependent on 
$(x+\delta x)$. So we can say that as {\boldmath$\delta x\longrightarrow 0$; 
$m_{PQ}\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}$}.

\end{document}
```

It takes some tricks to persuade LaTeX into indenting the paragraph in the tabular, but `\normalindent` can reveal handy also in other situations when you want to indent paragraph in a `\parbox` or `minipage`, where normal indentation is suppressed.

Never use `$$`; the `\Large$$\delta x$$` you had is simply achieved with a `center` environment.

I also scaled a bit the second `tikzpicture` or it wouldn't fit in the allotted space.

[image]

You can do it also without `tabular`, with some lower level tricks. The insertion is added at the start, as a zero width box containing another box as wide as the text width, where the insertion is placed at the far right margin.

Then the running text is set with a negative `\hangindent`, which makes the indentation at the right. The last line (containing the diagram) is centered with a nice trick involving `\leftskip` and `\rightskip`. We cover our tracks by issuing `\noindent` at the start of the text after the diagram.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm,tabularx,framed}

\geometry{a4paper, portrait, margin=1in}

\begin{document}

\subsection*{What is Differentiation?}

Differentiation is a mathematical tool used to find the \textbf{gradient of a tangent} to 
any general curve $y=f(x)$ at any desired point ($P$).
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4]
  \draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
  \draw[thick, color=gray,->] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {\textcolor{black}{$x$}};
  \draw[thick, color=gray, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {\textcolor{black}{$f(x)$}};
  \draw [color=red, semithick](-4,1).. controls(1,1.5).. (3.5,5);
  \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$P(x,y)$}] (P) at (1.15,2.15) {};
  \draw (3,4) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
  \draw (-1,3/5+0.05)--(3,34/10+0.05);
  \draw (-0.3,0.3) node[left]{tangent};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
In general, the steepness (i.e. gradient) of a curve at any point $P$ is the same as the 
gradient of the tangent at that point; i.e.
\[
m_{\text{tangent at $P$}}=m_{f(x)\text{ at $P$}}
\]
In calculus, $m_{f(x)\text{ at $P$}}$ is denoted
\[
\frac{d}{dx}(f(x))\qquad\text{or}\qquad\frac{dy}{dx}
\]
when the equation is defined in the form $y=f(x)$, and we call this general gradient the 
\textbf{derivative} of the curve.

\noindent
\makebox[0pt][l]{%
  \makebox[\textwidth][r]{%
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}%
    \smash{\colorbox{green!15}{%
    \begin{minipage}[t]{5cm}
    \textbf{Notation}
    \begin{center}
    \Large $\delta x$
    \end{center}
    The Greek letter $\delta$ (small-case delta) is a \textbf{prefix} to a variable and it 
    represents an infinitesimally small increase in that variable. It is not a distinct value.
    \end{minipage}}}%
  }%
}\indent
\hangindent=-\dimexpr5cm+12pt+6pt\relax\hangafter=0
\begingroup
\leftskip=0pt plus 0.5fil \rightskip=0pt plus -0.5fil
Consider now another point on our general curve, the point Q. This point 
is $\delta x$ away from $P$ horizontally and $\delta y$ away from $P$ vertically:\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[domain=0:4,scale=.95]
  \draw (0,-0.3) node[left]{$O$};
  \draw[thick, color=gray,->] (-4,0) -- (5,0) node[right] {\textcolor{black}{$x$}};
  \draw[thick, color=gray, ->] (0,-1) -- (0,5) node[above] {\textcolor{black}{$f(x)$}};
  \draw[color=blue] (1.15,2.15)--(3.3,4.7);
  \draw [color=red, semithick](-4,1).. controls(1,1.5).. (3.5,5);
  \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=below right:{$P(x,y)$}] (P) at (1.15,2.15) {};
  \node[circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=3pt,label=right:{$Q(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)$}] (Q) at (3.3,4.7) {};
  \draw (3,4) node[right]{$y=f(x)$};
  \draw (-1,3/5+0.05)--(3,34/10+0.05);
  \draw (-0.3,0.3) node[left]{tangent};
  \draw[dotted] (3.3,4.7)--(3.3,4.3);
  \draw[dotted] (3.3,3.7)--(3.3,0);
  \draw[dotted] (1.12,2.15)--(1.12,0);
  \draw[dotted] (3.3,4.7)--(0,4.7);
  \draw[dotted] (1.12,2.15)--(0,2.15);
  \draw[<->,dashed](-0.3,2.15)--(-0.3,4.7);
  \draw(-0.6, 3.4) node{$\delta y$};
  \draw[<->,dashed](1.15,-0.3)--(3.3,-0.3);
  \draw(2.3, -0.6) node{$\delta x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\par\endgroup

\noindent
The coordinates of $Q$ are $(x+\delta x,y+\delta y)$, shown above. We notice that if the 
values of $\delta x$ and $\delta y$ were to get smaller and smaller, the gradient of the 
chord $PQ$ (in blue) would approach that of the tangent at $P$, the gradient we wish to find 
($\frac{dy}{dx}$). We also know that the $y$-values of this graph are dependent on their 
respective $x$-value, since $y$ is defined as a function of $x$ ($y=f(x)$). So as $\delta x$ 
decreases, $\delta y$ will consequentially decrease because $(y+\delta y)$ is dependent on 
$(x+\delta x)$. So we can say that as {\boldmath$\delta x\longrightarrow 0$; 
$m_{PQ}\longrightarrow\frac{dy}{dx}$}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: @LukeCollins I was going to add a variant without `tabular`